# VB .NET Outlook 2016 Add-in Subject Line

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I am writing an add-in for Outlook 2016 using Visual Studio 2015.  I added a button to the built-in New Mail tab.  When clicked it adds the word "unencrypt" to the end of the subject line and then sends the email.

This works fine as long as the user has tabbed out of the subject line field after entering the subject.  But if you type in the subject and then immediately click the button it wipes out the subject line and replaces it with "unencrypt".

However, when I step through in debug it works fine - it keeps the existing text even if I haven't tabbed out of the subject line.  I figured there was some sort of delay in updating the Subject property of the mail item, but I manually put in a delay of 20 seconds and it still wiped out the subject line if I wasn't stepping through in debug.

I'm at a loss here.  Is there a way to check the subject line textbox itself?  or some other way to grab the text even if the user hasn't tabbed out?

Any help would be appreciated!

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Get the Application object
    Dim application As Outlook.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application

    ' Get the active Inspector object and check if is type of MailItem
    Dim inspector As Outlook.Inspector = application.ActiveInspector()
    Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = TryCast(inspector.CurrentItem, Outlook.MailItem)
    If mailItem IsNot Nothing Then
        If mailItem.EntryID Is Nothing Then
            If Not IsNothing(mailItem.Subject) AndAlso ((mailItem.Subject.Contains(" unencrypt")) OrElse (mailItem.Subject.Contains("unencrypt "))) Then
                mailItem.Subject = mailItem.Subject
            'ElseIf IsNothing(mailItem.Subject) Then
                'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000)
                'mailItem.Subject = mailItem.Subject + " unencrypt"
            Else
                mailItem.Subject = mailItem.Subject + " unencrypt"
            End If
            If Not IsNothing(mailItem.To) AndAlso mailItem.To.ToString().Trim <> "" Then
                mailItem.Send()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("We need to know who to send this to. Make sure you enter at least one name.", "Microsoft Outlook", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit:
Dmitry's answer got me where I needed, but for anyone else not familiar with the Windows API I added the code below and then simply called the GetSubject function from my original code instead of using the mailItem.Subject property.

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function FindWindowEx(ByVal parentHandle As IntPtr, _
                                        ByVal childAfter As IntPtr, _
                                        ByVal lclassName As String, _
                                        ByVal windowTitle As String) As IntPtr
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function FindWindow(ByVal lclassName As String, _
                                    ByVal lWindowName As String) As IntPtr
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowText(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
                                        ByVal lpString As StringBuilder, _
                                        ByVal nMaxCount As Integer) As Integer
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowTextLength(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

Private Function GetSubject(inspector As Outlook.Inspector) As String
    Try
        Dim inspectorHandle As IntPtr = FindWindow("rctrl_renwnd32", inspector.Caption)
        Dim windowLevel2Handle As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(inspectorHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "AfxWndW", "")
        Dim windowLevel3Handle As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(windowLevel2Handle, IntPtr.Zero, "AfxWndW", "")
        Dim windowLevel4Handle As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(windowLevel3Handle, IntPtr.Zero, "#32770", "")
        Dim SubjectHandle As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(windowLevel4Handle, IntPtr.Zero, "Static", "S&ubject")
        Dim SubjectTextBoxHandle As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(windowLevel4Handle, SubjectHandle, "RichEdit20WPT", "")
        Dim length As Integer = GetWindowTextLength(SubjectTextBoxHandle)
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder(length + 1)
        GetWindowText(SubjectTextBoxHandle, sb, sb.Capacity)

        Return sb.ToString()
    Catch
        Return ""
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: Small Note: There are 2 subject windows. ID 4101 and ID 4294. The one you need depends on the view. Simplified view of Outlook 2016 changes the subject window you need to 4101. In normal view it is ID4294 and both have a window with text "Subject". Only thing other then using both is to check SIZE. The window you do NOT want is 0,0 in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important part is that the subject edit box needs to lose focus for the OOM to become aware of the change.

You can use accessibility API or raw Windows API to access the contents of the edit box or you can try to focus some other inspector control, such as the message body editor.

Comment: I'm a complete newbie to Windows API, but Spy++ was able to get me what I needed and some Googling showed me how to use it.  Thanks for the pointer!